# Menu links and content to appear in different languages

Tags: 7

I have a small link in my page; when I click it, the whole website should come up in a different language, i.e. menus and the content. What modules should I need for this to be done perfectly?

For example, I saw [this website](http://www.rafedh.sa/), where alignment and layout also get changed a bit.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site is using the [Internationalization](http://drupal.org/project/i18n) module, but the different alignment, and layout is caused from a core feature Drupal has: When the language is one that is written from right to left, and a module adds a CSS file to the HTML output, e.g. using `drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'system') . '/system.admin.css');`, Drupal search a file named system.admin-rtl.css, and uses it when that file is present; otherwise, it just uses system.admin.css.

In that site, the files having that "extension" are the following ones:

- /modules/cck/theme/content-module-rtl.css
- /modules/filefield/filefield-rtl.css?
- /modules/nice_menus/nice_menus_default-rtl.css
- /modules/node/node-rtl.css
- /modules/poll/poll-rtl.css
- /modules/system/defaults-rtl.css
- /modules/system/system-rtl.css
- /modules/system/system-menus-rtl.css
- /modules/user/user-rtl.css
- /modules/views/css/views-rtl.css
- /themes/basic/css/style-rtl.css

To notice that, for example, /modules/poll/poll-rtl.css is not used instead of /modules/poll/poll.css, but together; /modules/poll/poll-rtl.css should then just contains the CSS styles that are specific for a right-to-left language.

The same is done for a left-to-right language; the difference is that Drupal looks for a file named, e.g., /modules/views/css/views-ltr.css, instead of /modules/views/css/views-rtl.css.

Comment: So when adding a page i need to add both english version and other language version content also. But how do i create multilingual menus?

Comment: Enable Translation and Internationalization  and you should see that every menu item has a language field. By selecting a specific language for that menu item you force it to show up only when you are viewing the site in that language. If you choose language neutral it will show on every language. If you have two languages in your site and you have lets say 10 menus items, then you need to make 10 menu items for one language and another ten for the other language.